# How to call method in stateful class from constructor in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call the `_read()` method from the `DataClass` constructor. Currently `_read()` is not defined in this class, however I need to make use of the `setState()` method which extends from the `State` class, so I cannot define it there. The ultimate goal is to use the `DataClass` constructor to create a widget using information passed to it from the `main` class. `_read()`will have to be called from the constructor for this to happen. My code is as follows:

```
import 'package:database/database_helpers.dart';

class DataClass extends StatefulWidget {

  String text;
  int IdNum;

  DataClass(int IdNum) {
    this.text = text;
    this.IdNum = IdNum;

    _read(); //This is where the problem is. This is not defined here.
  }

  @override
  _DataClassState createState() => _DataClassState();
}

class _DataClassState extends State<DataClass> {


  _read() async {
    DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    int rowId = widget.IdNum;
    Word word = await helper.queryWord(rowId);
    if (word == null) {
      print('read row $rowId: empty');
    } else {
      print('read row $rowId: ${word.word} ${word.frequency} ${word.otherNum}');
      setState(() {
        widget.text = 'row ${word.id}: ${word.word} ${word.frequency} ${word.otherNum}';
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 20,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Text(widget.text),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not move the `_read` method to the `initState` of your `DataClass` ? And use a `FutureBuilder` to update your UI when the `asynchronous read` method is done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to give a try to `initState()` method. `initState()` Is being called before your build method. If your widget tree is depending on the result of your `async _read()` function, you probably would need to show a loading indicator until your async function finished.

Official documentation of initState:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

Something like this:

```
class DataClass extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isLoading = false;
  String text;
  int IdNum;

  DataClass(int IdNum) {
    this.text = text;
    this.IdNum = IdNum;
  }

  @override
  _DataClassState createState() => _DataClassState();
}

class _DataClassState extends State<DataClass> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // Note that you cannot use `async await` in  initState
    widget.isLoading = true;
    _read().then((_) {
      widget.isLoading = false;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  _read() async {
    DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    int rowId = widget.IdNum;
    Word word = await helper.queryWord(rowId);
    if (word == null) {
      print('read row $rowId: empty');
    } else {
      print('read row $rowId: ${word.word} ${word.frequency} ${word.otherNum}');
      setState(() {
        widget.text =
            'row ${word.id}: ${word.word} ${word.frequency} ${word.otherNum}';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !widget.isLoading
        ? Container(
            child: Card(
              elevation: 20,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Text(widget.text),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for that @orotype, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Widget.DataClass
...

Comment: Where should I use Widget.DataClass? Will that help define the _read() method?